# How can I get steam to recognize existing game files (Far Cry 3)?

Tags: steam, far-cry-3

I've downloaded Far Cry 3 through the steam account on my laptop, then copied the files to the Steam account on my desktop PC. I've put the game folder into the common files folder, just as I always do when I copy a game from another computer. This has always worked before. But this time, steam is acting as if the files weren't there, and is trying to download all 10 GB of it, again.

I'm reasonably sure I've put the Far Cry file into the correct directory (steamapps\common). When I tell steam to open local files, it opens the correct Far Cry folder, which has all 10 GB of the required data in it, and when I tell steam to check the files for errors, it tells me everything's fine. And yet it keeps downloading the game and right now is telling me it's got 300 MB downloaded and ten hours to go. What can I do to make it recognize the existing files?

Answer (score 1):

You could always just use the export feature (menu, Steam, Import/Export or something along these lines), select only Far Cry 3 and use the same menu on your PC to import the game.

This should definitively pick it up, I've done the same few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer regarding import/export will work every time, but for your specific issue you could try one other thing.  Copy the files for far cry to the desktop or other folder.  Tell steam to delete local files for far cry (cancels download and deletes everything).  Close steam and copy far cry back from the desktop into the steamApps folder once steam is completely closed.  Reopen steam and tell it to install far cry.  It'll detect existing files and probably download a little bit (300 MB or less in my experience).  I think you probably had far cry downloading before you copied the files or stream was open at the time so it didn't see the files.  From now on use import and export to avoid issue though.